# How to display the weight in cart and checkout pages in Woocommerce depending on the country

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, converters, units-of-measurement

I'm working on my personnal website, and i'm struggling with weight units....  can you help me please ? 
First; i have this code that allows me to display item weight subtotal in cart and checkout pages.

```
// Display the cart item weight in cart and checkout pages

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_item_data', 10, 2 );
function display_custom_item_data( $cart_item_data, $cart_item ) {
    if ( $cart_item['data']->get_weight() > 0 ){
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => __( 'Weight subtotal', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value' =>  ( $cart_item['quantity'] * $cart_item['data']->get_weight() )  . ' ' . get_option('woocommerce_weight_unit')
        );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

But i would like to display the subtotals based on country automatically. For exemple if the customer is from USA or Canada i have to convert subtotals to lbs and inch instead of kg and cm.
I have already succeeded in the product page in the "additional information" area, using this code :

```
// For Weight
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_weight', 'imperial_format_weight', 20, 2 );
function imperial_format_weight( $weight_string, $weight ) {
    $country = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(); // Customer country
    $countries = array( 'US', 'LR', 'MM' ); // Imperial measurement countries

    if ( ! in_array( $country, $countries ) ) return $weight_string; // Exit

    $weight_unit = get_option( 'woocommerce_weight_unit' );

    $weight_string = wc_format_localized_decimal( $weight );
    if ( empty( $weight_string ) )
        return __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ); // No values

    if ( $weight_unit == 'kg' ) {
        // conversion rate for 'kg' to 'lbs'
        $rate = 2.20462;
        $label = ' lbs';
    } elseif ( $weight_unit == 'g' ) {
        // conversion rate for 'g' to 'oz'
        $rate = 0.035274;
        $label = ' oz';
    }

    return round( $weight * $rate, 2 ) . $label;
}
```

and now i would like to know how to display correctly this subtotal in cart and check out pages with the appropriate units per country.
thank you for your help !